# useSelector cause infinate loop in useEffect or passed props is not the newest state in redux

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

When i add columnext into useEffect dependencies it caused a infnate loop,but when i removed
columnext from denpendencies,the prop materialExtValues passed to my child Component MaterialForm is not the newest redux state but the previous state,my child component render the wrong data.I tried my solution on stackoverflow but can't get my except result,I am really confused,Who can help my out?

```
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import FormModal from '../../../../components/FormModal/FormModal';
import { FormType, ColumnExt } from '../../../../types';
import {
  MaterialValues,
  initialMaterialValues,
} from '../MaterialValues/MaterialValues';
import MaterialForm from './MaterialForm';
import { cvtNullToEmpty } from '../../../../helpers/cvtNullToEmpty';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { selectColumnExtDataSelector } from '../../../../redux/columnext/columnext.selector';
import {
  materialExtValues,
  ExtValues,
  EXT_KEYS,
} from '../MaterialValues/MaterialValues';
import { fetchColumnextsRequest } from '../../../../redux/columnext/columnext.action';

interface MaterialEditProps {
  editItem: string;
  initialValues: MaterialValues;
  handleClose: () => void;
}

const MaterialEdit: React.FC<MaterialEditProps> = ({
  editItem,
  initialValues,
  handleClose,
}) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const columnexts: ColumnExt[] = useSelector(selectColumnExtDataSelector);
  const [extValues, setExtValues] = useState<ExtValues>(materialExtValues);

  //get newest extValues
  const initExtValues = useCallback(() => {
    const colextFormData = new FormData();
    colextFormData.append('TableName', 'material');
    colextFormData.append('ObjectId', editItem);
    dispatch(fetchColumnextsRequest(colextFormData));
  }, [editItem, dispatch]);

  //combine newest extValues with old extValues
  const mergeMaterialExtValues = useCallback(() => {
    const materialExtMerge: ExtValues = {};

    columnexts.forEach((item) => {
      EXT_KEYS.forEach((key) => {
        if (item[key] !== '') {
          materialExtMerge[`${item.ColumnName}__${key}`] = item[key];
        }
      });
    });

    console.log('materialExtMerge', materialExtMerge);

    const newExts = Object.assign(materialExtValues, materialExtMerge);
    setExtValues((prev) => ({ ...prev, ...newExts }));

    console.log('materialExtValues', materialExtValues);
  }, [columnexts]);

  useEffect(() => {
    initExtValues();
  }, [initExtValues, columnexts]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (columnexts.length > 0 && columnexts[0].ObjectId === editItem) {
      mergeMaterialExtValues();
    }
  }, [mergeMaterialExtValues, editItem, columnexts.length]);

  return (
    <>
      <div className='material-edit'>
        <FormModal
          title='Edit Material'
          iconSrc='/assets/images/icons/material.png'
          handleClose={handleClose}
          renderDataForm={() => (
            <MaterialForm
              formType={FormType.EDIT}
              editItem={editItem}
              materialExtValues={extValues}
              initialValues={
                (cvtNullToEmpty(initialValues) as MaterialValues) ||
                initialMaterialValues
              }
              handleClose={handleClose}
            />
          )}
        />
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default MaterialEdit;
```

The code of selectColumnExtDataSelector is :

```
import { RootState } from "../rootReducer";
import { createSelector } from "reselect";



export const selectColumnExts = (state: RootState) =>
    state.columnext


export const selectColumnExtDataSelector = createSelector(
    [selectColumnExts],
    columnexts => columnexts.data
)
```

And ColumnExtReducer code is:

```
import { ColumnExt } from "src/types"
import { AnyAction } from 'redux';
import { columnextActionType } from "./columnext.types";

export interface ColumnExtState {
    data: ColumnExt[],
    loading: boolean;
    error: string | null;
}

const initialState: ColumnExtState = {
    data: [],
    loading: false,
    error: null
}

const columnextReducer = (state: ColumnExtState = initialState,
    action: AnyAction
) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case columnextActionType.FETCH_COLUMNEXTS_REQUEST:
            return { ...state, loading: true }
        case columnextActionType.FETCH_COLUMNEXTS_SUCCESS:
            return { ...state, loading: false, data: action.payload }
        case columnextActionType.FETCH_COLUMNEXTS_FAILURE:
            return { ...state, loading: true, error: action.payload }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default columnextReducer;
```

Comment: What is the code of `selectColumnExtDataSelector`?

Comment: I have added the code of selectColumExtDataSelector into post,it's : ` import { RootState } from "../rootReducer"; import { createSelector } from "reselect"; export const selectColumnExts = (state: RootState) => state.columnext export const selectColumnExtDataSelector = createSelector( [selectColumnExts], columnexts => columnexts.data ) `@phry

Comment: I fixed this problem,just by move this code ```const colextFormData = new FormData();
    colextFormData.append('TableName', 'material');
    colextFormData.append('ObjectId', editItem);
    dispatch(fetchColumnextsRequest(colextFormData));``` to higher order Component's useEffect.Thanks for your kindess!@phry